# Convert Row Data into Single Column w/ Key Column

Tags: mysql, sql, r, unpivot

I would like to convert row data into a single column with a key column from the original row data using SQL or R.

Example Row:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Customer #  | Item1   |   Item2   |   Item3  |  Item4 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1111111     | A12345  |   C45567  |   G34589 | A34529 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my desired result:

```
   -------------------------------
   | Customer # | Columnname | Value    |
   -------------------------------
   | 1111111    | Item1      | A12345   |
   | 1111111    | Item2      | C45567   |
   | 1111111    | Item3      | G34589   |
   | 1111111    | Item4      | A34529   |
```

Comment: In R, you can do a straightforward `reshape`: `reshape(df, varying=names(df)[-1], times=names(df)[-1], v.names="Value", timevar="Columnname", ids=NULL, new.row.names=1:1E5, direction="long")`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to *unpivot* the columns of your table to rows.

You tagged the question `mysqli`, so let me assume that you are using MySQL. In this database, you can use `union all`:

```
select customer, 'Item1' columname, Item1 value from mytable
union all select customer, 'Item2', Item2 from mytable
union all select customer, 'Item3', Item3 from mytable
union all select customer, 'Item4', Item4 from mytable
```

Other databases have neater solutions, typically using a lateral join and `values()`. In Postgres for example:

```
select t.customer, x.columname, x.value
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values 
    ('Item1', Item1), ('Item2', Item2), ('Item3', Item3), ('Item4', Item4)
) x(columname, value)
```

In SQL Server, you would just replace `cross join lateral` with `cross apply`.

Answer (score 1):

In R, you can use dplyr and tidyr as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- tibble(customer = c(11111),
               item1 = c('sfdhdshv'),
               item2 = c('dfh'),
               item3 = c('kjg'))

data

#   customer item1    item2 item3
#      <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr>
# 1    11111 sfdhdshv dfh   kjg 

data %>%
  pivot_longer(!customer, names_to = 'columnname', values_to = 'value')

#   customer columnname value   
#      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   
# 1    11111 item1      sfdhdshv
# 2    11111 item2      dfh     
# 3    11111 item3      kjg
```

Comment: Key thing in `r` is you can not have a column called `customer #` the `#` can't be there

Comment: `data.frame('Customer #' = 1, check.names = FALSE)[, 'Customer #']` @ChuckP

Comment: Lol okay yes you can go around but you're asking for trouble down the road